# Django Rest Framework: using DynamicFieldsModelSerializer for excluding serializer fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that is used in a couple of endpoints (generics.ListAPIView), but in one of them I need to hide a serializer field. I would prefer to not write a new serializer just to cover this case.

Starting from DRF 3.0 we have dynamic fields for serializers (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields), but I'm having some troubles to fully understand how to use them.

I created this serializer:

```
class TestSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    user_req = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    user_tar = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TestAssoc
        fields = ("user_req", "user_tar")
```

and this is my endpoint:

```
class TestEndpointListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'test_username'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ...
```

Now I need to hide the 'user_tar' field from the output, and according to the documentation I should instantiate the serializer with something like:

`TestSerializer(fields=('user_req'))`

but how should I do this inside my TestEndpointListAPIView? Should I override get_serializer?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT:**

I've found the following solution, by overriding the get_serialized function:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    kwargs['fields'] = ['user_req']
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'd like to know if it is a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this piece of code to `__init__` method of the serializer class as suggested in the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields):

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_req = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    user_tar = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TestAssoc
        fields = ("user_req", "user_tar")


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(TestSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

And so when you call the serializer from views.py do this :

```
TestSerializer(queryset, fields=('user_req'))
```

Alternatively what you can do is define a class

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Now import this class if you have defined it in some other file and then inherit it using

```
class TestSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
```

This way:

```
class TestSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    user_req = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    user_tar = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TestAssoc
        fields = ("user_req", "user_tar")
```

Now you can do

```
TestSerializer(queryset, fields=('user_req'))
```

**Update** 
In the views. Take an example of ListAPIView

```
class DemoView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = TestAssoc.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

            data = TestSerializer(queryset, fields=('user_req')).data

            return Response( {"data" : data } ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as error:
            return Response( { "error" : str(error) } , status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: This was my original thought, but then I failed to understood where `TestSerializer(queryset, fields=('user_req'))` should be placed in my ListAPIView.

Comment: I updated the answer you can now check.
I guess it solves all your querries.
If it solved then accept the answer so that others too can find it helpful

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't work (I get an empty json). Anyway it isn't `def get(self, request)`, but it is `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` and is ins't `{"data" : "data" }`, but it is `{"data" : data }`. Anyway the problem is that the variable data is empty.

Comment: Yeah `"data"` it was a typo which has been updated.

`*args, **kwargs` is not necessary unless you need it.
`get` method is still going to work without it.

And for the empty data which you are receiving in your `data` variable.
That's because `TestAssoc.objects.all()` here it's empty. You are not having any data of `TestAssoc` model.
So the empty json which you are getting has nothing to do with my code.